# Blocking multiple ip ranges using mod access in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ip, range, mod-access

I read the guide from apache site but I'm a bit confused, I'm trying to ban some ranges using this syntax:

```
order allow,deny
deny from 127.0.55.0/127.0.75.255
deny from 127.0.235.0/127.0.255.255
allow from all
```

But I think it's not working properly, probably the syntax is wrong or I'm using it in the wrong way, where should I write this text in htaccess? before the other lines or after? in the same htaccess file there're some mod rewrite script too (for anti-hotlinking).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've come to this answer using [apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_access.html).

You can give an address range using ip/netmask pair :

```
deny from 127.0.55.0/24
```

However, since range 55 - 75 are not power of two, I don't see how to make a range out of them. I'd add several rules.

```
order allow,deny
deny from 127.0.55.0/24  // Matches 55
deny from 127.0.56.0/21  // Matches 56 to 64
deny from 127.0.64.0/21  // Matches 64 to 71
deny from 127.0.72.0/22  // Matches 72 to 75

deny from 127.0.235.0/24 // Matches 235
deny from 127.0.236.0/22 // Matches 236 to 239
deny from 127.0.240.0/21 // Matches 240 to 255
allow from all
```

should work.

NB: Remove the comments after `//` before pasting into htaccess

Comment: I'm a bit newbie about IPs and htaccess, I thought the numbers in an IP are in ascending order, like: 127.0.55.0, 127.0.55.1, 127.0.55.2 etc, or it's not like that?

Comment: Sure it is. What I wrote in my answer are IP/Netmask pairs. A netmask allows grouping IP addresses (like a filter or a regexp does on text, the netmask does on the IP address). so 127.0.55.0/255.255.255.0 matches 127.0.55.* ; while 127.0.56.0/255.255.248.0 matches 127.0.64.0 to 127.0.71.255

Comment: For more explanation : [here](http://www.dslreports.com/faq/15216) is some step-by-step on calculating a subnet mask.

Comment: I tested this method but htaccess keeps ignoring the IPs, then I used a CIDR converter and this format is working now:
deny from 127.0.55.0/24
deny from 127.0.56.0/21
deny from 127.0.64.0/21
deny from 127.0.72.0/22

Comment: @KyousukeKyaa Thanks. I updated my answer to match your experience - for the record.

Comment: On apache 2.4 `deny from`  as been changed by `Require not ip` sources :  https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/fr/howto/access.html

Answer (score 0):

```
order allow,deny
deny from 2001:4200::/32
deny from 2001:4210::/32
deny from 2001:4218::/32
deny from 2001:4220::/32
deny from 2001:4228::/32
deny from 2001:4238::/32
deny from 2001:4248::/32
deny from 2001:4250::/32
allow from all
```

along these lines how to add a redirect to another website for a very long deny list that blocks a lot of countries in htaccess