# How do I set up apache 2.4.3 to deny certain address block ranges such as 10.1.0.0/24

Tags: apache, .htaccess

.htaccess files have now been replaced and that function is now under the httpd.conf file under apache/conf.

I would like to know the syntax of allowing everyone except several ranges of ip address blocks.

I have looked at the documentation for the different directives for the file but i have not found anything that does what i am looking to do.

the order command does not seem to work with deny,allow or even allow,deny

```
order deny,allow
deny from 10.1.0.0/24
```

or even

```
order allow,deny
deny from 10.1.0.0/24
```

I tried both ways and they both wont allow anyone to view my webpage if done that way. 
It is currently set to:

```
require all granted
```

under the  in the httpd.conf file.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18376573/blocking-multiple-ip-ranges-using-mod-access-in-htaccess) stack question.

Answer (score -1):

You may use `Deny` Directives in apache configuration to acheive that:

```
  deny from 10.1.0.0/16
```

more information avaiable [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_access.html).

Comment: I just made an edit where I just said what doesn't work. and that does not work. (not as intended at least. everything is blocked.)

Comment: @B4wii are you sure that you are modifying correct configuration file ?

Comment: As far as I can tell yes. this file has replaced all instances of the .htaccess according to the apache doccumentation. I'll post a link.
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html