# Tomcat Server under attack

Tags: security, tomcat7

Update:
Thanks Jerry. One of the hackers actually managed to upload an executable file that gained the root access to the server. The hackers directed the server to join a bit coin mining thingy.  The IT department does not want to block ips from certain country as we actually have an office there.  So I googled on how to make TOMCAT safer.  1. Deleted all the apps that come with the default installation in the webapps folder.  2. Do not use Tomcat web manager, deleted everything associated with it.  Hackers are trying to guess the admin user name and password. Having Tomcat admin app on is like dropping blood into the ocean full of sharks. The hackers will be attracted to your server.  After deleting the content of webapps, my server now returns a 404 code. I am still seeing some hacking activities from time to time, but after several 404 responses, they just stopped.

#

I looked at my Tomcat's access log and see the following entries. Looks like someone is trying to hack my server.  This is our testing server, no domain name and is only accessible by IP address. I have the Tomcat Admin web page enabled for debug purpose.

What is the hacker trying to achieve with all those get and post calls? Is the Tomcat server currently under attack or already been hacked? What can I do to stop the hacker?

```
198.108.66.176 - - [04/Dec/2018:00:06:28 -0600] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 -
198.108.66.176 - - [04/Dec/2018:00:06:28 -0600] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 -
196.52.43.116 - - [04/Dec/2018:01:07:31 -0600] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 302 -
92.52.204.77 - - [04/Dec/2018:01:29:58 -0600] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 -
41.223.49.173 - - [04/Dec/2018:02:07:00 -0600] "PROPFIND / HTTP/1.1" 302 -
41.223.49.173 - - [04/Dec/2018:02:07:00 -0600] "GET /webdav/ HTTP/1.1" 302 -
41.223.49.173 - - [04/Dec/2018:02:07:04 -0600] "GET /help.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
41.223.49.173 - - [04/Dec/2018:02:07:04 -0600] "GET /java.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
41.223.49.173 - - [04/Dec/2018:02:07:04 -0600] "GET /_query.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
41.223.49.173 - - [04/Dec/2018:02:07:04 -0600] "GET /test.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
41.223.49.173 - - [04/Dec/2018:02:07:05 -0600] "GET /db_cts.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
41.223.49.173 - - [04/Dec/2018:02:07:05 -0600] "GET /db_pma.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
41.223.49.173 - - [04/Dec/2018:02:07:05 -0600] "GET /logon.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
41.223.49.173 - - [04/Dec/2018:02:07:06 -0600] "GET /help-e.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
41.223.49.173 - - [04/Dec/2018:02:07:06 -0600] "GET /license.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
41.223.49.173 - - [04/Dec/2018:02:07:07 -0600] "GET /log.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
41.223.49.173 - - [04/Dec/2018:02:07:07 -0600] "GET /hell.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
41.223.49.173 - - [04/Dec/2018:02:07:07 -0600] "GET /pmd_online.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
41.223.49.173 - - [04/Dec/2018:02:07:08 -0600] "GET /x.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
41.223.49.173 - - [04/Dec/2018:02:07:08 -0600] "GET /shell.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
41.223.49.173 - - [04/Dec/2018:02:07:08 -0600] "GET /htdocs.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
41.223.49.173 - - [04/Dec/2018:02:07:08 -0600] "GET /desktop.ini.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
41.223.49.173 - - [04/Dec/2018:02:07:08 -0600] "GET /z.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
41.223.49.173 - - [04/Dec/2018:02:07:09 -0600] "GET /lala.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
41.223.49.173 - - [04/Dec/2018:02:07:09 -0600] "GET /lala-dpr.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
41.223.49.173 - - [04/Dec/2018:02:07:09 -0600] "GET /wpc.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
41.223.49.173 - - [04/Dec/2018:02:07:09 -0600] "GET /wpo.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
41.223.49.173 - - [04/Dec/2018:02:07:09 -0600] "GET /text.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
41.223.49.173 - - [04/Dec/2018:02:07:10 -0600] "GET /wp-config.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
41.223.49.173 - - [04/Dec/2018:02:07:10 -0600] "GET /muhstik.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
41.223.49.173 - - [04/Dec/2018:02:07:11 -0600] "GET /muhstik2.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
41.223.49.173 - - [04/Dec/2018:02:07:11 -0600] "GET /muhstiks.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
41.223.49.173 - - [04/Dec/2018:02:07:11 -0600] "GET /muhstik-dpr.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
41.223.49.173 - - [04/Dec/2018:02:07:12 -0600] "GET /lol.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
41.223.49.173 - - [04/Dec/2018:02:07:12 -0600] "GET /uploader.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
41.223.49.173 - - [04/Dec/2018:02:07:12 -0600] "GET /cmd.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -

41.223.49.173 - - [04/Dec/2018:02:07:16 -0600] "POST /wuwu11.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
41.223.49.173 - - [04/Dec/2018:02:07:16 -0600] "POST /xw.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
41.223.49.173 - - [04/Dec/2018:02:07:16 -0600] "POST /xw1.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
41.223.49.173 - - [04/Dec/2018:02:07:16 -0600] "POST /9678.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
41.223.49.173 - - [04/Dec/2018:02:07:17 -0600] "POST /wc.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
41.223.49.173 - - [04/Dec/2018:02:07:17 -0600] "POST /xx.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
41.223.49.173 - - [04/Dec/2018:02:07:17 -0600] "POST /s.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
41.223.49.173 - - [04/Dec/2018:02:07:18 -0600] "POST /w.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
41.223.49.173 - - [04/Dec/2018:02:07:19 -0600] "POST /sheep.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
41.223.49.173 - - [04/Dec/2018:02:07:19 -0600] "POST /qaq.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
41.223.49.173 - - [04/Dec/2018:02:07:20 -0600] "POST /db.init.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
41.223.49.173 - - [04/Dec/2018:02:07:20 -0600] "POST /db_session.init.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
41.223.49.173 - - [04/Dec/2018:02:07:20 -0600] "POST /db__.init.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
41.223.49.173 - - [04/Dec/2018:02:07:20 -0600] "POST /wp-admins.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
41.223.49.173 - - [04/Dec/2018:02:07:20 -0600] "POST /m.php?pbid=open HTTP/1.1" 302 -
41.223.49.173 - - [04/Dec/2018:02:07:21 -0600] "POST /db_dataml.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
41.223.49.173 - - [04/Dec/2018:02:07:21 -0600] "POST /db_desql.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
41.223.49.173 - - [04/Dec/2018:02:07:21 -0600] "POST /mx.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
41.223.49.173 - - [04/Dec/2018:02:07:22 -0600] "POST /wshell.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
41.223.49.173 - - [04/Dec/2018:02:07:23 -0600] "POST /xshell.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
41.223.49.173 - - [04/Dec/2018:02:07:23 -0600] "POST /qq.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
41.223.49.173 - - [04/Dec/2018:02:07:23 -0600] "POST /conflg.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
41.223.49.173 - - [04/Dec/2018:02:07:24 -0600] "POST /lindex.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
41.223.49.173 - - [04/Dec/2018:02:07:24 -0600] "POST /phpstudy.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
41.223.49.173 - - [04/Dec/2018:02:07:24 -0600] "POST /phpStudy.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
41.223.49.173 - - [04/Dec/2018:02:07:24 -0600] "POST /weixiao.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
41.223.49.173 - - [04/Dec/2018:02:07:24 -0600] "POST /feixiang.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
41.223.49.173 - - [04/Dec/2018:02:07:25 -0600] "POST /ak47.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
41.223.49.173 - - [04/Dec/2018:02:07:25 -0600] "POST /ak48.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
41.223.49.173 - - [04/Dec/2018:02:07:25 -0600] "POST /xiao.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
41.223.49.173 - - [04/Dec/2018:02:07:26 -0600] "POST /yao.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
41.223.49.173 - - [04/Dec/2018:02:07:27 -0600] "POST /defect.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
41.223.49.173 - - [04/Dec/2018:02:07:27 -0600] "POST /webslee.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
41.223.49.173 - - [04/Dec/2018:02:07:28 -0600] "POST /q.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
41.223.49.173 - - [04/Dec/2018:02:07:28 -0600] "POST /pe.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
41.223.49.173 - - [04/Dec/2018:02:07:28 -0600] "POST /hm.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
41.223.49.173 - - [04/Dec/2018:02:07:28 -0600] "POST /cainiao.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
41.223.49.173 - - [04/Dec/2018:02:07:28 -0600] "POST /zuoshou.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
41.223.49.173 - - [04/Dec/2018:02:07:29 -0600] "POST /zuo.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
41.223.49.173 - - [04/Dec/2018:02:07:29 -0600] "POST /aotu.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
41.223.49.173 - - [04/Dec/2018:02:07:29 -0600] "POST /cmd.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
41.223.49.173 - - [04/Dec/2018:02:07:29 -0600] "POST /bak.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
41.223.49.173 - - [04/Dec/2018:02:07:30 -0600] "POST /system.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
41.223.49.173 - - [04/Dec/2018:02:07:30 -0600] "POST /l6.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
41.223.49.173 - - [04/Dec/2018:02:07:30 -0600] "POST /l7.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
41.223.49.173 - - [04/Dec/2018:02:07:31 -0600] "POST /l8.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
41.223.49.173 - - [04/Dec/2018:02:07:31 -0600] "POST /q.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > What is the hacker trying to achieve with all those get and post calls?

To find an exploit they might leverage; could be known filenames for software with known bugs/holes; probably by now there have been similiar requests from different addresses one might suspect.

> > Is the Tomcat server currently under attack or already been hacked?

Attack -- if there was a status 200 in the logs then maybe hack. The logs above all showed 302/redirect; so one could assume the hack was not fruitful.

> > What can I do to stop the hacker?

Do whois on the ip address; block the range reported -- odds are it is from a country you don't or want to do business with.  ;)   Best if traffic can be dropped (or blocked) at the internet demarc (gateway/router).  Apache can also be configured as well -- see below:

[Blocking multiple ip ranges using mod access in htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18376573/blocking-multiple-ip-ranges-using-mod-access-in-htaccess)